# Can anyone help me runbootstrap on internet explorer 7?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, internet-explorer-7

Can anyone help me run bootstrap on internet explorer 7 and 8?I tried many time but failed.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: Is there possiblity to run bootstrap on ie7 or 8?

Comment: Read the link i posted. All the information is available on the Bootstrap website.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: sir , I use your comment as copy paste but it's not work for me.

Comment: Sir ,I use it in head portion with its comments <!--[if lt IE 9]>............<![endif]--> , But sir it not work.So Sir,Can you tell me the way to add this code?

Comment: sir,i done this but sir now i again failed.Sir, I used in head tags but it's not work.